# do we have to explicitly mention the not null constraint for a primary key?

Tags: mysql, sql, primary-key

Do we have to explicitly mention that a primary key shouldn't be null, when creating a table? Even if we don't mention the 'not null' constraint for the primary key, SQL wouldn't allow us to insert a NULL value into the primary key field. therefore which of the following is a good practice?

```
1)    create table registration(
        id int primary key,
        name varchar(10)

    )

2)     create table registration(
        id int primary key not null,
        name varchar(10)

    )
```

Comment: Good practice would be explicitly stating `NOT NULL`. It isnt too much of a change, and generally SQL Studio would do that for you. Follow the guidelines here for a good example. http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_primarykey.asp

Comment: invisible effect ....

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[No](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/create-table.html) you don't.

> A PRIMARY KEY is a unique index where all key columns must be defined
>   as NOT NULL. If they are not explicitly declared as NOT NULL, MySQL
>   declares them so implicitly (and silently). A table can have only one
>   PRIMARY KEY. The name of a PRIMARY KEY is always PRIMARY, which thus
>   cannot be used as the name for any other kind of index.

I'd however consider it good practice to state it explicitly - as that makes things more clear,
and you don't have to look it up this rule every time you're in doubt.

Answer (score 0):

Ask yourself, for the sake of it, why would you *not* if it makes something, not necessarily less clear without it, but more explicitly clear? Following this, I see no reason to omit it and perfectly valid reasons to emit it in the script.

The best practice is generally the most sensible one.